# Removing Rows in Varying Instances in a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, row

I have 5 basketball dataframes from 5 different years that look like so:

```
Player                Team
Quincy Acy            SAC
Jordan Adams          MEM
Steven Adams          OKC
...                   ...
Chris Andersen        TOT
Chris Andersen        MIA
```

Notice the same person, `Chris Andersen`, appears twice, indicating they moved teams mid-season. `TOT` represents the "total" row for the average stats throughout the season, regardless of the team. This occurs several times throughout all of the dataframes.

My question: How do I remove all of the rows for that player that are not `TOT`. In other words, I want to keep the `TOT` row for that player. Also, I have a reason for not combining the dataframes at the moment. I would imagine that there is a way to do this with a for loop, which is what I tried, but I cannot figure out an efficient way to hunt down all the players that were on multiple teams and remove the unwanted rows.

For `Chris Andersen`, I want the `TOT` to be the only row I keep. `TOT` only appears for players who have moved teams, so it does not apply to all players - it varies.

I want the result of the dataframe to look like this:

```
Player                Team
Quincy Acy            SAC
Jordan Adams          MEM
Steven Adams          OKC
...                   ...
Chris Andersen        TOT
```

Comment: TOT only appear for players in multiple teams? Or does TOT appear for all players? Providing a replicable example, what you have tried and what you want to accomplish will be a lot clearer than what you have described at the moment.

Comment: won't `filter(Team == TOT)` suffice?

Comment: @JahiZamy not really, as that will only filter out players that have moved.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I didn't think that one through lol

Comment: tidyverse approach: `df %>% add_count(player) %>% filter(n == 1 | n > 1 & team=="TOT") %>% select(-n)`

Comment: Like Magic, thanks, Adam